# Convert Single Page Tiff to Multiple Page Tiff Folder Wise C# (50000 Tiff Files)

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap, tiff, image-conversion

I'm trying to develop a desktop application that converts multiple images into Multi-page Tiff for each folder.

I try the following code but It's throwing an error when folder have a large amount of file having 1MB size.

```
public bool saveMultipage(Image[] bmp, string location, string type)
        {
            if (bmp != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    ImageCodecInfo codecInfo = getCodecForstring(type);

                    for (int i = 0; i < bmp.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (bmp[i] == null)
                            break;
                        bmp[i] = (Image)ConvertToBitonal((Bitmap)bmp[i]);
                    }

                    if (bmp.Length == 1)
                    {

                        EncoderParameters iparams = new EncoderParameters(1);
                        Encoder iparam = Encoder.Compression;
                        EncoderParameter iparamPara = new EncoderParameter(iparam, (long)(EncoderValue.CompressionCCITT4));
                        iparams.Param[0] = iparamPara;
                        bmp[0].Save(location, codecInfo, iparams);


                    }
                    else if (bmp.Length > 1)
                    {

                        Encoder saveEncoder;
                        Encoder compressionEncoder;
                        EncoderParameter SaveEncodeParam;
                        EncoderParameter CompressionEncodeParam;
                        EncoderParameters EncoderParams = new EncoderParameters(2);

                        saveEncoder = Encoder.SaveFlag;
                        compressionEncoder = Encoder.Compression;

                        // Save the first page (frame).
                        SaveEncodeParam = new EncoderParameter(saveEncoder, (long)EncoderValue.MultiFrame);
                        CompressionEncodeParam = new EncoderParameter(compressionEncoder, (long)EncoderValue.CompressionCCITT4);
                        EncoderParams.Param[0] = CompressionEncodeParam;
                        EncoderParams.Param[1] = SaveEncodeParam;

                        File.Delete(location);
                        bmp[0].Save(location, codecInfo, EncoderParams);


                        for (int i = 1; i < bmp.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if (bmp[i] == null)
                                break;

                            SaveEncodeParam = new EncoderParameter(saveEncoder, (long)EncoderValue.FrameDimensionPage);
                            CompressionEncodeParam = new EncoderParameter(compressionEncoder, (long)EncoderValue.CompressionCCITT4);
                            EncoderParams.Param[0] = CompressionEncodeParam;
                            EncoderParams.Param[1] = SaveEncodeParam;
                            bmp[0].SaveAdd(bmp[i], EncoderParams);

                        }

                        SaveEncodeParam = new EncoderParameter(saveEncoder, (long)EncoderValue.Flush);
                        EncoderParams.Param[0] = SaveEncodeParam;
                        bmp[0].SaveAdd(EncoderParams);
                    }
                    return true;


                }
                catch (System.Exception ee)
                {
                    throw new Exception(ee.Message + "  Error in saving as multipage ");
                }
            }
            else
                return false;

        }
```

In this function, I'm passing an Array of Image object that contains images of the current folder.

While I'm preparing an array of Image, at that time application throws an `Out of Memory` exception.

Please provide a solution for that.

Thank you.

Comment: 50k clearly is too many, make chunks, like say 25k of them, so combined-part1, combined-part2 etc

Comment: I have debugged the code tool throws an exception after adding 500 files having size 1 MB.

Comment: what part exactly is throwing the memory exception

Answer (score 0):

@Hiren Patel,

You can try below code for splitting the multipage tiff into individual pages in a separate folder.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         string fileName = @"D:\TiffContainer\MultipageTiffImage.tif";

         using (Image imageFile = Image.FromFile(fileName))
         {
            FrameDimension frameDimensions = new FrameDimension(
                imageFile.FrameDimensionsList[0]);

            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(imageFile);
            int frameNum = imageFile.GetFrameCount(frameDimensions);
            string[] paths = new string[frameNum];

            for (int frame = 0; frame < frameNum; frame++)
            {
               // Selects one frame at a time and save as jpeg. 
               imageFile.SelectActiveFrame(frameDimensions, frame);

               paths[frame] = String.Format("{0}\\{1}{2}.tif",
                            Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName),
                            Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName),
                            frame);
               bmp.Save(paths[frame], ImageFormat.Tiff);
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Hope it will be helpful.